# Flexbox - image on the right side

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an image on the right side item of a flex container. As you can see in the codepen, there is a gap when expanding the screen (caused by the max-width on the image, which is unavoidable).

However I'm just wanting to move that image to the extreme right-side, so the gap isn't as noticeable.

This needs to be friendly with IE11, and the image needs to be responsive. I would like to avoid using a float on the image if possible (would've thought there is a cleaner way of achieving this using flexbox)?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.stevensegallery.com/1000/1400">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus aliquid eius quia expedita illo sequi optio labore assumenda.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.container > .image {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}
.image > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
.container > .text {
  flex: 2 0 0%;
}
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/neilem/pen/zjpXKZ

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://codepen.io/IIalejoII/pen/mLpgGg

Comment: @AlejandroTorres - this doesn't work when you add `max-height:` on the img though, as the gap will then reappear. I'm giving an upvote because this is definitely an alternative option!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `vertical-align` instead `display`, then `text-align`:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.container > .image {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  text-align:right;/* and here*/
}
.image > img {
  vertical-align:top;/* here */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
.container > .text {
  flex: 2 0 0%;
  /* and eventually */
  
  margin:auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.stevensegallery.com/1000/1400">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus aliquid eius quia expedita illo sequi optio labore assumenda.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't need to add `text-align:right;` and `vertical-align:top;` Only add `float: right;` in `.image > img`. This is enough.

Comment: @NitinBisht - I wanted to avoid using floats because I'm not too familiar with when/if I'd need to clear them etc.

Comment: @G-Cyr - I think that works, I'm going to test this some more when I get home later. Although just working out how that works and mine didn't (as I tried using `text-align:`)? Not sure I understand why adding `vertical-align:top` would solve it?

Comment: @NitinBisht it indeed works, but here display:blocks tells me that at first that the OP was probably dealing with the gap beneath the image and also probably wrap the image to avoid side effects of img being a direct  flex child. img are inline-box and can be easily  treated as such, No need here to reset display or use float.

Comment: @n1234 remove `vertical-align` to find out what effect(without display reset) it has (the gap under the image) img is an inline-box and stands on the baseline alike text (the gap is used by some  letters, so `jpqy` do not overlap on next line ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Use justify-content property on container and remove flex properties form the flex-child. Your code will look like this. Hope the result is what you desired.

```
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;

  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```